# Missing advanced network settings for iPhone USB/Bluetooth tethering

Tags: iphone, tethering, proxy

My iPhone is tethered to my Mac laptop via Bluetooth or USB.

I want to set up a proxy on my Mac for use with the iPhone network interface, but unfortunately in Mac OS X 10.6, under System Preferences -> Network, the iPhone Bluetooth and iPhone USB network interfaces lack the standard options under the Advanced… tab. These Advanced… options are available in other interfaces (e.g., Airport, Ethernet, etc.).

I want to use the polipo caching proxy for tethered browsing, but I am unable to define an HTTP Proxy in the GUI, since these options are missing.

The prefpane windows for my tethered iPhone's network interfaces (Bluetooth & USB)  is missing the normal options for network interfaces.

Does anyone know a command line workaround for setting up an HTTP proxy, or some way of modifying the prefpane settings for the iPhone network interfaces?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `networksetup` command. For example:

```
sudo networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy "iPhone USB" localhost 8888
```

Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html

Comment: Here are some more examples for google to index: `sudo networksetup -setwebproxy "Bluetooth PAN" localhost 8118` and
`sudo networksetup -setsecurewebproxy "Bluetooth PAN" localhost 8118`